# deserializeUser called multiple times by client requirejs app

Tags: node.js, express, requirejs, passport.js

My node/express/passport app works fine, but when I include my client requirejs app (which resides inside the /public/js/ folder) like this in my jade template:

```
script(src="js/vendor/requirejs/requirejs.js", data-main="js/main")
```

passport calls deserializeUser multiple times.

My static folder is declared before passport is initialized in my main.js:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

The client requirejs project is not optimized by r.js, so it has to load the needed javascript files. When the client project is optimized by r.js it works fine - no extra deserialize calls (just 1).

Is this desired behavior for passport? It's not a huge problem as it's doing this in development, but is this a solvable issue?

Comment: I recommend you to try to load the js file alone directly in the browser and see if this triggers a user deserialization. If this is the case there is something very strange going on because express.static should stop the middleware chain once it serve the file.

Comment: @yeiniel I visited the files it's calling and they don't cause the deserializer to run, could it be something else? When the project is optimized into 1 file, it doesn't happen, so I do think requirejs is causing it

Comment: @user1930226 Solutions must be posted a actual answers, not as edits to  the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can add a logger middleware to your application like morgan and try to correlate the deserialization occurrence to specific static file by looking at the sequence of http request logs and logs associated to the deserialization call.